# How to use copy_if() polymorphically?

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism

This code attempts to use copy_if() on a vector of polymorphic pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AbstractBase
{
    public:
        virtual bool IsDerived1() const { return false; }
        virtual void Print() const = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public AbstractBase
{
    public:
        virtual bool IsDerived1() const { return true; }
        virtual void Print() const { cout << "Derived1" << endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public AbstractBase
{
    public:
        virtual void Print() const { cout << "Derived2" << endl; }
};

// This function returns the elements of v that are of type Derived1.
vector<Derived1*> SelectDerived1(const vector<AbstractBase*>& v)
{
    vector<Derived1*> derived1s;

#define USE_COPY_IF 0

#if USE_COPY_IF
    // attempt to use copy_if - does not compile:
    //     /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:990:6:
    //     error: invalid conversion from 'AbstractBase*' to 'Derived1*'
    //     [-fpermissive]
    copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), derived1s.begin(),
            [](AbstractBase* elem){ return elem->IsDerived1(); });
#else
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        if ((*it)->IsDerived1())
            derived1s.push_back(static_cast<Derived1*>(*it));
#endif

    return derived1s;
}

int main()
{
    vector<AbstractBase*> v;
    Derived1* d1 = new Derived1;
    Derived2* d2 = new Derived2;
    v.push_back(d1);
    v.push_back(d2);

    vector<Derived1*> derived1s = SelectDerived1(v);
    for (auto it = derived1s.begin(); it != derived1s.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->Print();

    delete d1;
    delete d2;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and works fine with USE_COPY_IF set to 0:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test_copy_if.cc
$ ./a.out 
Derived1
```

But I could not manage to get it work with copy_if() - see the error message in the comment.

Isn't there a way?

Comment: You are aware that this is not type-safe in general, even taking the `elem->IsDerived1()` check into account? (Anyone can create a new subclass which is not a subtype of `Derived1` but returns `true` from `IsDerived1`.)

Comment: That `static_cast` you do in your manual copying, that's not done by `std::copy`, so it tries to copy from a collection containing one type to a collection of a completely different type which of course will not work.

Comment: You could combine `copy_if` (with `dynamic_cast`, and into another vector of `AbstractBase*`) and `std::transform` for the casting.

Comment: @Mahesh Are you sure that you set USE_COPY_IF to 1?! The code in your link shows it's still set to 0.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to define a function `transform_if` (which is missing in the standard):

```
template <class InIt, class OutIt, class Pred, class Trafo>
OutIt transform_if (
    InIt begin_in, InIt end_in,
    OutIt begin_out,
    Pred predicate,
    Trafo trafo
) {
    OutIt itout = begin_out;
    for (InIt itin = begin_in; itin != end_in; ++itin) {
        if (predicate (*itin)) {
            (*itout) = trafo (*itin);
            ++itout;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
transform_if(v.begin(), v.end(), derived1s.begin(),
        [](AbstractBase* elem){ return elem->IsDerived1(); },
        [](AbstractBase* elem){ return static_cast<Derived1*> (elem); }
);
```

Or define a `transform_and_keep_if` doing the check after the transformation:

```
template <class InIt, class OutIt, class Trafo, class Pred>
OutIt transform_and_keep_if (
    InIt begin_in, InIt end_in,
    OutIt begin_out,
    Trafo trafo,
    Pred predicate
) {
    OutIt itout = begin_out;
    for (InIt itin = begin_in; itin != end_in; ++itin) {
        auto transformed = trafo (*itin);
        if (predicate (transformed)) {
            (*itout) = transformed; // or std::move (transformed)
            ++itout;
        }
    }
}
```

and then write:

```
transform_and_keep_if(v.begin(), v.end(), derived1s.begin(),
        [](AbstractBase* elem){ return dynamic_cast<Derived1*> (elem); },
        [](Derived1* elem){ return elem != NULL; },
);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `std::function` here?

Comment: It's more flexible, as you can pass any function-like object. You will need std::function as soon as you catch local variables inside the `[]` of the lambda function, as then the lambda will be an object.

Comment: Lambda is always an object, even if it  doesn't catch anything. You can still pass any function-like object if you templatize the last two parameters. Anything that can be used as a postfix expression in a function call will just work. `std::function` is useful when you want to store function objects somewhere. Here, it is unnecessary clutter.

Comment: You mean `template<class InIt, class OutIt, class Pred, class Trafo> OutIt transform_if ( /*...*/ Pred pred, Trafo trafo ) { ... }`? Tend to agree that's better (shorter, at least).

Answer (score 0):

You could partition `v` in one pass with `std::partition` to put all the `Derived1` pointers at the beginning of your vector and then call `std::transform` to actually do the copying.  The code would look like this:

```
    auto deriveds_end = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(),
                                       [](AbstractBase* e){
                                           return e->IsDerived1();
                                       });
    std::transform(v.begin(), deriveds_end,
                   std::back_inserter(derived1s),
                   [](AbstractBase* e){
                       return static_cast<Derived1*>(e);
                   });
```

The only catch here is that std::partition modifies the sequence it's partitioning, which means you can't pass `v` by const reference, you can pass it by copy or by non-const reference instead (if you don't mind `v` getting rearranged when you call the function).

If it were me however, I would just stick with the loop:

```
    for(auto i : v)
        if(i->IsDerived1())
            derived1s.push_back(static_cast<Derived1*>(i);
```

It doesn't get much more succinct than that.